# Mapping "http://intranet" to a web application

Tags: url, web-application, iis, dns

A customer of mine wants a user to be able to type "http://intranet" into their url and have their web application load. typing their web applications is rediculous because the url is nonsensical, I don't know how that happened. I am not a Network Engineer, and don't know how to do this. They have created the DNS forward lookup "A" record for "http://intranet".

Bonus points if you can explain a little bit about what is going on behind the scenes :)

Answer (score 0):

You can configure this by

1. Adding `http://intranet` in the Alternate Access Mapping - From SharePoint Central Admin
2. DNS must be configured with an A record for each Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN). The A record points to the load balanced IP address for the Web servers hosting a site. In a typical production deployment, servers are configure with statically assigned IP addresses, as well as statically assigned A records in DNS.

Details can be read http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2011/05/25/coordinating-urls-with-aam-and-dns.aspx

http://blog.blksthl.com/2012/12/03/a-guide-to-alternate-access-mappings-basics-in-sharepoint-2013/

https://min2dmax.wordpress.com/2012/06/15/customize-sharepoint-url-using-aam-and-dns/

Comment: Thanks! Not quite there yet though. Comments edit http, apologies for the '/'.  "http:/intranet" works if I type the top level site for the home site collection in. So I am typing 'http:/intranet/xxx/sites/HomeTest' which isn't what the client is looking for.